# Custom Edittext Hiding pin bar after text is inputted

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-edittext, android-appcompat

I'm a beginner android developer and trying to create a Custom Pin Edittext using the following code and i want to set the color of the pin to transparent if filled,unfortunately there is no state_filled in the attr of android, how should i do that? Help me please here is my code.

```
public class PinEntryEditText extends AppCompatEditText {
public static final String XML_NAMESPACE_ANDROID = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";

private float mSpace = 24; //24 dp by default, space between the lines
private float mCharSize;
private float mNumChars = 6;
private float mLineSpacing = 8; //8dp by default, height of the text from our lines
private int mMaxLength = 6;

private OnClickListener mClickListener;

private float mLineStroke = 1; //1dp by default
private float mLineStrokeSelected = 2; //2dp by default
private Paint mLinesPaint;
int[][] mStates = new int[][]{
        new int[]{android.R.attr.state_selected}, // selected
        new int[]{android.R.attr.state_focused}, // focused
        new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_focused}, // unfocused

};

//Green color = 0xFFB6C800
//Gray color = 0xFFCCCCCC
int[] mColors = new int[]{
        0xFFB6C800,
        0xFFCCCCCC,
        0xFF880000,
};

ColorStateList mColorStates = new ColorStateList(mStates, mColors);

public PinEntryEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public PinEntryEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs);
}

public PinEntryEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context, attrs);
}

private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    float multi = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    mLineStroke = multi * mLineStroke;
    mLineStrokeSelected = multi * mLineStrokeSelected;
    mLinesPaint = new Paint(getPaint());
    mLinesPaint.setStrokeWidth(mLineStroke);
    setBackgroundResource(0);
    mSpace = multi * mSpace; //convert to pixels for our density
    mLineSpacing = multi * mLineSpacing; //convert to pixels for our density
    mMaxLength = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(XML_NAMESPACE_ANDROID, "maxLength", 4);
    mNumChars = mMaxLength;

    //Disable copy paste
    super.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        }

        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    // When tapped, move cursor to end of text.
    super.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setSelection(getText().length());
            if (mClickListener != null) {
                mClickListener.onClick(v);
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l) {
    mClickListener = l;
}

@Override
public void setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(ActionMode.Callback actionModeCallback) {
    throw new RuntimeException("setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback() not supported.");
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //super.onDraw(canvas);
    int availableWidth = getWidth() - getPaddingRight() - getPaddingLeft();
    if (mSpace < 0) {
        mCharSize = (availableWidth / (mNumChars * 2 - 1));
    } else {
        mCharSize = (availableWidth - (mSpace * (mNumChars - 1))) / mNumChars;
    }

    int startX = getPaddingLeft();
    int bottom = getHeight() - getPaddingBottom();

    //Text Width
    Editable text = getText();
    int textLength = text.length();
    float[] textWidths = new float[textLength];
    getPaint().getTextWidths(getText(), 0, textLength, textWidths);

    for (int i = 0; i < mNumChars; i++) {
        updateColorForLines(i == textLength);
        canvas.drawLine(startX, bottom, startX + mCharSize, bottom, mLinesPaint);

        if (getText().length() > i) {
            float middle = startX + mCharSize / 2;
            canvas.drawText(text, i, i + 1, middle - textWidths[0] / 2, bottom - mLineSpacing, getPaint());
        }

        if (mSpace < 0) {
            startX += mCharSize * 2;
        } else {
            startX += mCharSize + mSpace;
        }
    }
    //mLinesPaint.setColor(getColorForState(0xff1a1f71));
}


private int getColorForState(int... states) {
    return mColorStates.getColorForState(states, Color.GRAY);
}

/**
 * @param next Is the current char the next character to be input?
 */
private void updateColorForLines(boolean next) {
    if (isFocused()) {
        mLinesPaint.setStrokeWidth(mLineStrokeSelected);
        mLinesPaint.setColor(getColorForState(android.R.attr.state_focused));
        if (next) {
            mLinesPaint.setColor(getColorForState(android.R.attr.state_selected));
        }
    } else {
        mLinesPaint.setStrokeWidth(mLineStroke);
        mLinesPaint.setColor(getColorForState(-android.R.attr.state_focused));
    }
}
```

}

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

there is no state_filled but you can create one. you can use TextWatcher interface it will be triggered whenever text will be updated. you can check there if current text size is equal to your mMaxLength set your pin color to transparent or else.
here is an example of TextWatcher implementation :

```
et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
});
```

Comment: I would like to set the color on my Custom class since i will reuse it, is there anyway i can change the pin color using my code directly?

Comment: as long as its edit text you can set TextWatcher wherever you want. just add it inside your custom class and it should do the tick